# Removing brackets from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pandas, tuples

My data is a list of tuples :

```
def find_ngrams(verbatims, n):
  return zip(*[verbatims[i:] for i in range(n)])

bigrams = find_ngrams(verbatims, 4)
print bigrams
```

`[((u'a', u'grossir', u'et', u'a'), 74), ((u'un', u'avis', u'de', u'passage'), 68), ((u'le', u'facteur', u'est', u'pass\xe9'), 67), ((u'V\xeatements', u'+', u'ou', u'-'), 63), ((u'+', u'ou', u'-', u'similaires'), 62), ((u'vous', u'ne', u'pouvez', u'pas'), 54), ((u'sinon', u'une', u'petite', u'recherche'), 53)]`

ordered and counted using the Counter().most_common() method :

```
ngrams = Counter(bigrams).most_common()
```

FIY I am doing an n-gram analysis on a large text data. For n-gram information : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram 
I have a cool dataframe in pandas :

```
DF = pandas.DataFrame(ngrams)
DF.columns = ['ngram','occurence']
print DF
                                               ngram  occurence
0                                (a, grossir, et, a)         74
1                            (un, avis, de, passage)         68
2                          (le, facteur, est, passé)         67
```

Except that my n-grams are enclosed with brackets, and I don't want that. I know I could use a basic search/replace method, but I want to do it in a more computer science, logic way. Plus if I do a search/replace, I could lose some brackets from inside of my text.

I'm not sure what is the exact problem here but I guess it has to do with the nested tuples inside of my list. So how do I take a list of tuples to a dataframe without having brackets ?

edit : as requested, here is my expected output :

```
                                               ngram  occurence
0                                 a, grossir, et, a         74
1                             un, avis, de, passage         68
2                           le, facteur, est, passé         67
```

Thanks,

Comment: what's your expected output? what you ask for is unclear and not mentionned.

Comment: I edited my question with my expected output.

Comment: I do not have the same result simply when I get DF ... can you recheck your data?

Answer (score 1):

You are not simply looking for:

```
In [309]: pd.DataFrame([(','.join(el[0]), el[1]) for el in bigrams])
Out[309]:
                            0   1
0              a,grossir,et,a  74
1          un,avis,de,passage  68
2        le,facteur,est,passé  67
3            Vêtements,+,ou,-  63
4           +,ou,-,similaires  62
5          vous,ne,pouvez,pas  54
6  sinon,une,petite,recherche  53
```